# Implementation : Phone number validation fails with google-libphonenumber

Tags: javascript, node.js, libphonenumber

Numbers starting with 8209****** shows invalid number for the given region 'IN'. Here is the npm runkit demo for the same.

https://runkit.com/592d3e4bb70f37001158b54d/592d3e4bb70f37001158b54e

However, the API call with the latest version of google-libphonenumber, shows the accurate result.

http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/phonenumberparser?number=%2B91+8209895324

My assumption is there is something wrong with the implementation.

Here is the complete implementation as it is from npm runkit of google-libphonenumber.

```
var phoneUtil = require("google-libphonenumber").PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
var phoneNumber0 = "+918209000000";
var phoneNumber1 = "+918197800510";
var phoneNumber2 = "+918209890000";
var phone0 = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber0); 
var phone1 = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber1); 
var phone2 = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber2);
console.log(phoneUtil.isValidNumber(phone0)); // failed
console.log(phoneUtil.isValidNumber(phone1)); // success 
console.log(phoneUtil.isValidNumber(phone2)); // failed
```

Comment: can you use regex instead??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Unfortunately, no. I had earlier filed this as a bug and they mentioned that it is not. Just wanted to know what exactly is wrong with the implementation as it is working for all other numbers except this series.

Comment: @SushimMukulDutta are you sure that they are valid phone numbers?

Comment: @talentedandrew yes they are, please check the API call to the library.
http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/phonenumberparser?number=%2B91+8209895324. 
The number used here is also the third case in the code, which fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** : This is was a [bug](https://github.com/seegno/google-libphonenumber/issues/110) in the wrapper google-libphonenumber, w which was resolved in the release 2.0.18. Test [run](https://runkit.com/592d3e4bb70f37001158b54d/5943e689f31b6d0012bed903).